# Google offline speech recognition for desktop development

Tags: voice-recognition, speech-to-text

In Android development I know there is offline speech recognition available from Google Now for third-party apps. I was wondering does an offline language pack/API exist for desktop applications or does such a thing exist for Android only? And yes I am aware of CMU Sphinx, Julius, the Google speech recognition API (which only has 50 uses per day) and other programs, I was just wondering. Thanks!

Comment: It's only available on Android.

Comment: That's what I thought, just making sure. Thanks!

Comment: Now it's 2019, does google release some offline STT voice recognition API? Thanks!

Comment: Now it's 2021, does google release some offline STT voice recognition API? Thanks!